# How would I use moq to test a MongoDB service layer?

Tags: c#, mongodb, moq

I have a service layer between my app and the mongo database.

I'm trying to build a unit test using moq 
I'm quite new to moq so I started with what I thought would be a trivial test.

Code to test:

```
    public List<BsonDocument> GetAllSettings()
    {
        var collection = MongoDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Settings");
        var query = from e in collection.AsQueryable()
                    select e;

        var settings = query.ToList();
        return settings;
    }
```

Where:
Settings is a Collection 
MongoDatabase is a MongoDBDriver.MongoDatabase

I've tried this as my test:

```
    [Test()]
    public void GetAllSettingsTest()
    {
        //Arrange
        BsonDocument doc01 = new BsonDocument();
        BsonDocument doc02 = new BsonDocument();

        var mongoDatabase = new Mock<MongoDatabase>();
        var collection = new Mock<MongoCollection<BsonDocument>>();
        mongoDatabase.Setup(f => f.GetCollection(MongoCollection.Settings)).Returns(collection.Object);
        collection.Object.Insert(doc01);
        collection.Object.Insert(doc02);

        ILogger logger = new Logger();
        DatabaseClient.DatabaseClient target = new DatabaseClient.DatabaseClient(logger);
        target.MongoDatabase = mongoDatabase.Object;

        MongoCursor<BsonDocument> cursor = collection.Object.FindAllAs<BsonDocument>();

        List<BsonDocument> expected = cursor.ToList();
        List<BsonDocument> actual;

        //Act
        actual = target.GetAllSettings();

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
```

I'm getting an error of "Could not find a parameterless constructor" at:

mongoDatabase.Setup(f => f.GetCollection(MongoCollections.Settings)).Returns(collection.Object);

The error refers to the MongoCollection object.  I didn't think it had a constructor.

What can I do to get my test to run?

Comment: Donot mock, `var collection = new Mock<MongoCollection<BsonDocument>>();` and try

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 7):

this question is most probably related to: [How do I mock MongoDB objects to test my data models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903532/how-do-i-mock-mongodb-objects-to-test-my-data-models)

Anyway, here is minimal Moq configuration required to mock

```
        var message = string.Empty;

        var serverSettings = new MongoServerSettings()
        {
            GuidRepresentation = MongoDB.Bson.GuidRepresentation.Standard,
            ReadEncoding = new UTF8Encoding(),
            ReadPreference = new ReadPreference(),
            WriteConcern = new WriteConcern(),
            WriteEncoding = new UTF8Encoding()
        };

        var server = new Mock<MongoServer>(serverSettings);
        server.Setup(s => s.Settings).Returns(serverSettings);
        server.Setup(s => s.IsDatabaseNameValid(It.IsAny<string>(), out message)).Returns(true);

        var databaseSettings = new MongoDatabaseSettings()
        {
            GuidRepresentation = MongoDB.Bson.GuidRepresentation.Standard,
            ReadEncoding = new UTF8Encoding(),
            ReadPreference = new ReadPreference(),
            WriteConcern = new WriteConcern(),
            WriteEncoding = new UTF8Encoding()
        };

        var database = new Mock<MongoDatabase>(server.Object, "test", databaseSettings);
        database.Setup(db => db.Settings).Returns(databaseSettings);
        database.Setup(db => db.IsCollectionNameValid(It.IsAny<string>(), out message)).Returns(true);

        var mockedCollection = collection.Object;
```

Anyway, as I mentioned in linked question, this might not be useful when any of inner-workings of MongoDriver change.

Comment: Seems to be missing ... `var collection = new Mock<MongoCollection<YOURTTYPE>>(database.Object, "COLLECTIONNAME", collectionSettings);` and some appropriate collectionSettings.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by inner-working of MongoDB Driver change? Do you mean the changes to API C# MongoDB Driver when you upgrade to a newer version of the C# MongoDB Driver?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not familiar with the MongoDbDriver.MongoDatabase, but if it works like I think it does, then you can't mock it directly. You need to abstract the MongoDB access code, and mock that. That would be an actual unit test. e.g.

```
public interface IMongoDBRepository
{
   Collection<T> GetCollection<T>(string name) where T BsonDocument;
}

public class MongoDbRepository : IMongoDBRepository
{
   public Collection<T> GetCollection<T>(string name) 
     where T : BsonDocument
   {
      return MongoDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(name);
   }
}
```

Now, in your code, you inject an IMongoDBRepository (using whatever DI method you like) and your code would looks something like this:

```
private IMongoDBRepository _mongoDBRepository; //this gets injected
public List<BsonDocument> GetAllSettings()
{
    var collection = _mongoDBRepository.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Settings");
    var query = from e in collection.AsQueryable()
                select e;

    var settings = query.ToList();
    return settings;
}
```

And finally your unit test:

```
[Test()]
public void GetAllSettingsTest()
{
    //Arrange
    BsonDocument doc01 = new BsonDocument();
    BsonDocument doc02 = new BsonDocument();

    var mongoDatabase = new Mock<IMongoDBRepository>();
    var collection = new Mock<MongoCollection<BsonDocument>>();
    mongoDatabase.Setup(f => f.GetCollection(MongoCollection.Settings)).Returns(collection.Object);
    collection.Object.Insert(doc01);
    collection.Object.Insert(doc02);

   //rest of test
}
```

Comment: This has given me some stuff to consider but won't work as it is.  You can't inject a IMongoDBRepository object into the method. The code must use a MongoDatabase not a IMongoDBRepository as it must read a real database when running.

Comment: Also, MongoDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(name); can't be done as GetCollection is not a static method.  I'll use the basic idea and see if I can get it to function.