# Connecting MongoDB to mock database and creating collections

Tags: c#, mongodb, moq

I have this code that's supposed to create a mock Mongodb database. I'm trying to create a collection of name `students` and write bson data to it. However, for some reason the returned collection is always null in this line `var collection = db.GetCollection < BsonDocument > ("students");`. I'm suspecting it's because I am not configuring the db properly or the mock database is not working.
Any help is appreciated!

```
 public async Task CreateMock() {
   var dbMock = new Mock < IMongoDatabase > ();
   var resultCommand = new BsonDocument("ok", 1);
   dbMock
    .Setup(stub => stub.RunCommandAsync < BsonDocument > (It.IsAny < Command < BsonDocument >> (), It.IsAny < ReadPreference > (), It.IsAny < CancellationToken > ()))
    .ReturnsAsync(resultCommand)
    .Verifiable();

   var mongoClientMock = new Mock < IMongoClient > ();
   mongoClientMock
    .Setup(stub => stub.GetDatabase(It.IsAny < string > (), It.IsAny < MongoDatabaseSettings > ()))
    .Returns(dbMock.Object);

   var db = dbMock.Object;

   db.CreateCollection("students");
   var collection = db.GetCollection < BsonDocument > ("students");

  var document = new BsonDocument
                {
                    {"firstname", BsonValue.Create("Peter")},
                    {"lastname", new BsonString("Mbanugo")},
                    { "subjects", new BsonArray(new[] {"English", "Mathematics", "Physics"}) },
                    { "class", "JSS 3" },
                    { "age", 45}
                };

   collection.InsertOne(document);
```

Comment: Reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257198/how-would-i-use-moq-to-test-a-mongodb-service-layer

Comment: but also, why mock a db when you can just connect to a local instance of Mongo and just test that directly?

Comment: yeah i agree with @SomeStudent i've never needed to mock mongodb. even in ci/cd, just install mongodb on-the-fly and run your integration tests on a test database.

Comment: also [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9BaDj8SSsdM) might be of interest if you're a fanatic mocker.